# C# SOAP client unable to deserialize response ("There is an error in XML document")

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, serialization, soap

I added a reference to a Web Service in my project. I'm using the generated code to call the methods of the Web Service. One of the methods returns the following structure:

```
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:typens="urn:AllegroWebApi" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
       <SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
          <typens:doGetCatsDataResponse>
             <cats-list xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="typens:CatInfoType[24051]">
                <item xsi:type="typens:CatInfoType">
                   <cat-id xsi:type="xsd:int">26013</cat-id>
                   <cat-name xsi:type="xsd:string">Antyki i Sztuka</cat-name>
                   <cat-parent xsi:type="xsd:int">0</cat-parent>
                   <cat-position xsi:type="xsd:int">0</cat-position>
                   <cat-is-product-catalogue-enabled xsi:type="xsd:int">0</cat-is-product-catalogue-enabled>
                </item>
            ....

            </item>
            <item xsi:type="typens:CatInfoType">
               <cat-id xsi:type="xsd:int">124895</cat-id>
               <cat-name xsi:type="xsd:string">Pozostałe</cat-name>
               <cat-parent xsi:type="xsd:int">124883</cat-parent>
               <cat-position xsi:type="xsd:int">5</cat-position>
               <cat-is-product-catalogue-enabled xsi:type="xsd:int">0</cat-is-product-catalogue-enabled>
            </item>
            <item xsi:type="typens:CatInfoType">
               <cat-id xsi:type="xsd:int">124894</cat-id>
               <cat-name xsi:type="xsd:string">Teleskopy</cat-name>
               <cat-parent xsi:type="xsd:int">124883</cat-parent>
               <cat-position xsi:type="xsd:int">6</cat-position>
               <cat-is-product-catalogue-enabled xsi:type="xsd:int">0</cat-is-product-catalogue-enabled>
            </item>     // Line 168361   <--------------- HERE
         </cats-list>
         <ver-key xsi:type="xsd:long">91632766</ver-key>
         <ver-str xsi:type="xsd:string">1.1.47</ver-str>
      </typens:doGetCatsDataResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The generated code that is responsible for deserializing it throws the following exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.Xml.dll Additional information: There is an error
>   in XML document (168361, 13).

I marked the line that is mentioned in the exception in the code sample. I guess it has something to do with the fact that it is the closing tag of the last `item` object. I have no idea why it is failing. The XML is well formated and does not seem to include any unsupported characters.

Comment: You could first try to validate your xml, there are a couple of solutions online, like http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_validate.asp. Or open it in Firefox or IE, in the case of exceptions they should mark the exact line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, but check your data, could be one of the fields has a '<' or '>' throwing off the formatting of the xml document.

Comment: Oops should learn to read the whole question, you already tried that :-)

Comment: That was in fact the case. I used a simple regex and found a tag that contained the "<" character as it's contents thus messing up the parsing process. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have two closing item tags in a row.  Granted, you may be excluding some of the XML file.  Still, two closing tags in a row would certainly cause that error.